# self-reference model in pydantic

Tags: python, recursion, filesystems, pydantic

I would like to  serialize a structure with has self-references:

```py
class FileSystemEntry(BaseModel):
    id: str
    path: str | None = None
    mime_type: str | None = None
    is_directory: bool
    parent: FileSystemEntry | None = None
    children: List[FileSystemEntry] = []
    share_link: AnyHttpUrl | None = None
```

how to do it? Obviously when try to dump it to JSON, I have

`pydantic_core._pydantic_core.PydanticSerializationError: Error serializing to JSON: ValueError: Circular reference detected (id repeated)`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your case, need to write the custom serialization method to handle circular references.

```
from typing import List, Dict, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, AnyHttpUrl

class FileSystemEntry(BaseModel):
    id: str
    path: str | None = None
    mime_type: str | None = None
    is_directory: bool
    parent: Union['FileSystemEntry'] = None
    children: List['FileSystemEntry'] = []
    share_link: AnyHttpUrl | None = None

    def to_serializable(self) -> Dict:
        """Converts the model to a dictionary format that can be serialized."""
        # Serialize without children to avoid circular references
        serialized_data = self.dict(exclude={'children', 'parent'})
        # Manually serialize the children and parent (only ID for simplicity)
        if self.parent:
            serialized_data['parent'] = self.parent.id
        serialized_data['children'] = [child.id for child in self.children]
        return serialized_data

# Example usage
parent_entry = FileSystemEntry(id="1", path="/", is_directory=True)
child_entry = FileSystemEntry(id="2", path="/child", is_directory=False, parent=parent_entry)

parent_entry.children.append(child_entry)

print(parent_entry.to_serializable())
```

Answer (score 0):

### My Answer

- To use `self-reference` inside a `class`, you should use `quotes` to represent itself.
- Currently, it is not supported to use `|` to union types with quotes representation so use `typing.Union` instead.
  And `typing.Union[XXX, None]` is equivalent to `typing.Optional[XXX]`.

### My Example

```py
from platform import python_version_tuple
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import VERSION, BaseModel

print(python_version_tuple())
# > ('3', '11', '5')

print(VERSION)
# > 2.3.0


class Model(BaseModel):
    model: Optional['Model'] = None
    models: list['Model'] = []


m = Model(model=Model(), models=[Model()])
print(m.model_dump_json())
# > {"model":{"model":null,"models":[]},"models":[{"model":null,"models":[]}]}
```